# Can I init a iostream from a buffer without copying it?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a buffer `unsigned char *buffer` filled with `size` bytes. I wanna init a stream from it.

I can do it as follow, which copys the buffer bytes:

```
string s(bytes, bytes + size);
stringstream ss(s);
```

I wonder if I can init a stream without that copy?

Comment: why would you want to do that?  There's no way to do that AFAIK

Comment: to save the copy time

Comment: have you proved that this is a problem in your code? How large is your buffer?

Comment: The real question is why you're using a character buffer in the first place. If you're writing C++ code, everything should be using the `string` class in the first place, which would solve all of your problems (and more).

Comment: @CodyGray Because I need to call the third lib to read data from a zip file.

Comment: @TonyTheLion The copy shouldn't be a problem in my app. I just wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: To do that, you'll probably have to derive your own `streambuf` class and construct an `istream` from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `streambuf` that you then pass to the `istream` constructor. This will allow you to access the array data as any other stream. See the following links for more details:

1. [std::streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/)
2. [std::istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/)

Boost provides the iostreams library for helping with this. In particular, it already provides the `array_source` class for wrapping standard arrays. The following code sample illustrates how to accomplish this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>


namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char buffer[] = "buffer data\n";

    io::array_source src{ buffer, strlen(buffer) };
    io::stream_buffer<io::array_source> strbuf{ src };

    std::istream stream{ &strbuf };
    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: boost::iostreams [copies the data into a buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/source.html)

Comment: @MarcoKinski Not sure how the link you posted gives this information. Could you provide more detail?

Comment: @TAS boost::iostreams::stream_buffer delegates the work to a "Device". "Source" is a "Device" for input purposes and this interface gives you no alternative as to copy the data into a buffer.